# SAS Web services payload size - http 413 error

Tags: web-services, sas, sas-stored-process

I have developed a stored process to receive an XML file as a response to a web service call and deployed it as a web service - something similar to the example [here](https://support.sas.com/kb/63/438.html).

It is successful and working fine in receiving an XML file which is of ~100KB but **failing** to **receive** similar file which is about **3MB**. The other system sending the response seems to throw the below error

`HTTP Response Code 413 for 'https://mystoredprocessURL'`. I understand that this is related payload too large in size.

Could you suggest me how to configure the length of payload size that has to be received so that the stored process can receive a larger file. Tried to research but could not find anything relevant.

Comment: Does the `proc http` run 30 seconds in a normal way then stop and throw an error? If so, set the 'timeout' option bigger and try it again.

Answer (score 0):

my first idea. I hope this helps, but that's just a hint:

```
SAS SMC-->plug-ins tab-->Application manager-->configuration manager-->
SAS Application infrastucture-->BI web services for java 9.4-->WebServiceMaker
-->Settings tab-->Attachemnt optimized threshold block. 
Maybe the default size is 2048.
```